# Resignation during probation period without notice

Tags: resignation

I am working as a laborer for five months now but now got a skill job offer which require me to start work urgent. I spoke with my present company and then put in my resignation. But the company is asking me to pay for the visa cost because i did not complete the six months.
Please help me throw some insight.

Comment: Check your employment contract. There are plenty of employers with clauses like this. For example, if the company pays for your higher education and you don't stay an employee for at least two years, you are required to pay your employer back.

Comment: What country are you in? What sort of visa did you get? Depending on these factors what they're asking might be outright illegal ...

Answer (score 3):

Check the terms of the contract you signed for your current job. It should mention notice periods and if there are any costs that are repayable if you leave within set timescales.

Can you work another month as a labourer? Most skilled jobs will expect a notice period of at least a month.

Comment: Notice periods probably vary from place to place. In the US, 2 weeks is often the expected notice period and a month would be pretty generous.